# Injecting menuItem tags as string

Tags: c#, string, winforms, properties, tooltip

In Visual Studio 2010 with winforms on C#, I am using a `statusStrip` as my tooltip viewer. For most `Controls` including `buttons` and `textBoxes` I'm using the `Tag` property, converted to a string, and injecting it as the text in the `statusStrip` with event `MouseEnter`; the string is replaced at `MouseLeave`.

I want to be able to do the same thing with `MenuItems`, however it appears that they aren't being handled as `Controls` the same. I've set up a "debug" string such that I know when `Tag` fails to be injected, and this is how I know that the `MenuItems` are not being handled the same.

The code for both methods `tooltipEnter` and `menuItemTooltipEnter` are as follows:

```
    //Injects sender tag as string into status strip (used for Controls)
    private void tooltipEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var c = sender as Control;
        if (c == null) { toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "null(0)"; return; }

        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = Convert.ToString(c.Tag);
    }

    //Injects sender tag as string into status strip (used for MenuItems)
    private void menuItemTooltipEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var c = sender as MenuItem;
        if (c == null) { toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "null(0)"; return; }

        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = Convert.ToString(c.Tag);
    }
```

As you can see, whenever I enter a "`Control`" with the mouse, the string is injected into the `statusStrip`. I have this code working.

But when pointing `menuItem` event `mouseEnter` at the either `tooltipEnter` or `menuItemTooltipEnter`, both inject "null(0)" into the `statusStrip`.

Can someone tell me why `menuItem` `Tags` aren't handled the same way as, say, `textBox` `Tags`? What can I do to remedy this situation?

Comment: I don't understand your problem well, do you mean you want when mouse is over your **menu item**, the **menu item Text** should be shown on the `statusStrip`? BTW, what kind of `menu` are you using? We have `Menu`, `MenuStrip`, `ContextMenu` and `ContextMenuStrip`

Comment: Apparently the term I was using, `menuItem`, was faulty. I should have been using `toolStripMenuItem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you are using a `ToolStripMenuItem`, and not a `MenuItem`. Both classes have nothing to do with each other, and thus when `sender` is of type `ToolStripMenuItem`, the result of

```
var c = sender as MenuItem;
```

will always be `null`.

Use this instead:

```
    //Injects sender tag as string into status strip (used for MenuItems)
    private void menuItemTooltipEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var c = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
        if (c == null) { toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "null(0)"; return; }

        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = Convert.ToString(c.Tag);
    }
```